# How do I set the application startup order in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, boot

Win 10 is too automatic for my taste and I can't even get an start order of the programs.

How do I easily set the startup order for programs?

I tried using MSconfig which doesn't work any more, and the start up menu just takes some and registry take some and it's messed up badly.

Comment: Hi Tommy. I tried to edit your question to remove some material which I felt was excessive, in order to focus on the problem you are having. However, I couldn't quite work out what you meant with the second half of what is now the final sentence so I basically left that alone. Could you clarify one thing: **Are you referring to application startup order after logging in?** Because "startup order" could also refer to e.g. the startup order of Windows services, which is configured separately. You can [edit] your question to clarify this part.

Comment: [Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/52043/how-to-control-the-order-of-startup-programs-in-windows/) you can find some native tricks and 3rd party apps to do this. You can also achieve it using [TaskScheduler](https://superuser.com/a/416190/616090).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/416182/control-sequence-of-startup-programs-in-windows

Answer (score -2):

In order to disable or enable startup items please open your task manager by hitting " CTRL + SHIFT + ESC " or by using " CTRL + ALT + DELETE and select task manager " when task manager is opened switch to the tab called " Startup " there you can chose what application starts with windows .

And if you want to disable services startup open the run dialog box by hitting " windowskey + r " and type in " services.msc " there you can disable or enable services that starts automatically with windows .

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question at all.

Comment: @InterLinked where else startup programs in msconfig are located in older windows versions ?

Comment: @InterLinked I suggest you re-read the question before you drop your down votes

Comment: He is not asking where they are located, he is asking how to change the order. You did not address that at all in your answer.

Comment: He addressed " it doesn't work anymore " since when you could set the priority of the startup items in Msconfig?

Comment: You are the one who needs to read the question. He already knows how to disable and enable services. He wants to know how to change the order services are started. The way your answer is worded does not answer the question currently. If you can edit it to make it better, please do. Regardless of whether programs are services are concerned, you have only address enabling or disabling them. Your answer is either unclear or does not answer the question. I know you mean well; your answer as currently worded however does not answer the question.

Comment: @InterLinked he mentioned programs not services btw so I think I read it well. Let OP comment for clarification if needed .