# Priority of Startup Programs in Windows 11

Tags: boot, windows-11, logitech-mouse, windows-11-v22h2

I have a Logitech gaming mouse and I'm using the "Logitech Gaming Software" as it doesn't function without it. The issue is "LGCore" process starts very late in comparison to other startup apps on Windows (for some reason), therefore, leaving me waiting to use the mouse to do anything. Is there a way to prioritize that process so that it starts faster?

Comment: It's a good question, but has been asked and answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/416182/control-sequence-of-startup-programs-in-windows . However, there are many locations from which a process can be initiated, e.g., Registry *Run & Run Once*, Windows User and All *Startup* folders, Scheduled Task, or as a Windows Service. Use Sysinternals' Autoruns, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns , to try to turn off some of the undesired startup processes.